# page fault doens't occur though I flushed cache before access memory(file-mmaped memory)

Tags: python, memory, linux-kernel, mmap, page-fault

I wrote simple code which occur page-fault via python.
the process is as below.

i) make a temp file and mmap via np.memmap() api

ii) fill the memory

iii) flush memory

iv) access memory by index

I **expected page fault in the iv) step.** I used perf trace to monitor page fault.
(*sudo perf trace -F maj --no-syscalls*)
**But page fault didn't happened.**
Below is my full python code.

```
import mmap
import os
from time import sleep
import timeit
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import Optimizer
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
import random
import math
from time import time


*#ref: np.memmap usage: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/mmap-vs-zarr-hdf5/*
from tempfile import mkdtemp
import os.path as path
filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'newfile.dat') #make tmp file in the /tmp/tmp*/newfile.dat


data_size = 10240*10240
data = np.arange(data_size, dtype='float32')
data.resize((10240,10240))

#step i)
fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode = 'w+', shape=(10240,10240))

#step ii)
fp[:] = data[:] #this occur page fault to file /tmp/tmp*/newfile.dat

#step iii)
fp.flush()
os.system('sudo sh -c "sync; echo 3 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"')
sleep(5)

#step iv)
'''
Bellow four access accur 4 page fault to file /tmp/tmp*/newfile.dat
if do 'fp[:] = data[:]' before these, fault doesn't occur though I flush cache before access.
'''
print(fp[0])
print(fp[100])
print(fp[1000])
print(fp[10000])
```

is there anything I missed?

I tried access array 'fp' by index without filling(e.g., fp[:] = data[:]). If I access array 'fp' without filling, page fault occur.

If I skip process ii) and iii), page fault occur in the step iv) as bellow

```
 14353.230 ( 0.000 ms): sudo/63776 majfault [0x7fc101575004] => /tmp/tmpz00lweix/newfile.dat@0x4 (d.)
 14355.719 ( 0.000 ms): sudo/63776 majfault [0x7fc10195d004] => /tmp/tmpz00lweix/newfile.dat@0x3e8004 (d.)
 14357.331 ( 0.000 ms): sudo/63776 majfault [0x7fc103c85004] => /tmp/tmpz00lweix/newfile.dat@0x2710004 (d.)
 14357.658 ( 0.000 ms): sudo/63776 majfault [0x7fc119c15004] => /tmp/tmpz00lweix/newfile.dat@0x186a0004 (d.)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You are better off testing this kind of low level stuff in C, not Python + Numpy, which add one thousand different layers of abstractions on top of the OS.